# PDE with substitution - proving the correctness of the substitution

Tags: differential-equations, education

I have the differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial z^2}$$

to solve it, the author of my book carries out the following replacement:

$$-2\zeta \frac{dX}{d \zeta} = \frac{d^2 X}{d \zeta^2}$$

with $X=1-\frac{C}{C_S}$ and $\zeta =\frac{z}{(4Dt)^{1/2}}$.

How can I prove that the last equation is identical to the first in Mathematica?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Could you please describe the substitution z->zeta in detail? What means Dt?

Comment: Hello @UlrichNeumann, D is a constant, z and t are variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

straightforward:

```
pde = Derivative[1, 0][C][t, z] == d Derivative[0, 2][C][t, z]

Simplify[pde /. C -> Function[{t, z}, CS (1 - X[z/Sqrt[4 d t]])] /.z -> \[Zeta] Sqrt[4 d t] ]   
(* (CS (2 \[Zeta] Derivative[1][X][\[Zeta]] + (
X^\[Prime]\[Prime])[\[Zeta]]))/t == 0 *)
```

which confirms the replacement!

Comment: Your solution is extremely clear @UlrichNeumann!